# Weird internet issue in my Kubuntu

Tags: networking, kubuntu, internet, vpn

I messed up with the system while trying to install a VPN and one day my wifi stopped working, then after a while I tried to install Windscribe VPN and my whole internet connection stopped working even when I'm wired and the only thing that fixes it is when I run a complete system scan with Bleachbit. Does anyone know how to fix this? Also sorry I can't give much details because I don't really know whats happening.

Comment: have a look into your journalctl -u NetworkManager and dmesg logs

Comment: password is hellomotto https://www.protectedtext.com/internetlog